# How to set finite value to maxoccurs instead of "unbounded" in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, xsd

I have a WCF service. When I expose my service, all my Datacontracts are getting converted to element and also an "ArrayOf" for each element with ComplextType tag. In ComplextType tag, the maxOccurs is getting default value as "unbounded".

But actually I want to over write this maxOccurs value and set a finite value(Eg: maxOccurs="10") for each element inside "ArrayOf" in the generated XSD files.

I tried implementing IXMLSerializable, didn't work. Can someone please help me put on this?

**Note:** for both service and data contracts namespace is different

**My Service Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceApplicationFault), Action = ServiceApplicationFault.FaultContractAction)]
    EmployeeModel GetDetails(String EmpId);
}
```

**My Data Contract**

```
[DataContract]
public class EmployeeModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpDept { get; set; }

}
```

**My Generated XSD**

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfEmployeeModel">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="EmployeeModel" nillable="true" type="tns:EmployeeModel"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfEmployeeModel" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfEmployeeModel"/>
<xs:complexType name="EmployeeModel">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EmpId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EmpName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EmpDept" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="EmployeeModel" nillable="true" type="tns:EmployeeModel"/>
```

Comment: Can you show us the data contracts that you're exposing?

Comment: I cannot share actual service contract.. But I can show an example that looks alike.

Comment: And can you add the EmployeeModel too?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3hx2s7e(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which of these members are being converted to Arrays? It seems like there should be just one of each.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I read same article earlier.. But I didnt get idea where to implement it. I am new to WCF. Can you brief me on this?

Comment: I am getting one element for EmployeeModel and one complextype for that element inside which all members are defined. Apart from that, another "ArroyOf" element for same EmployeeModel in which I am getting the maxOccurs="unbounded" for EmployeeModel element.

Comment: It appears to me that your service returns EmployeeModel[], not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found solution for my question. We can do this by over writing the generated XSD schema. Over writing this schema can be done by implementing **IContractBehavior, IWsdlExportExtension** interfaces.

Step1: Create a class with name with suffix "Attribute" and implement Attribute class and IContractBehavior, IWsdlExportExtension to that class.

Step 2: Add this class as an attribute to your service contract.

Step3: Now implement your requirement in the method IWsdlExportExtension.ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context). At this point you will be having metadata information available.

For more info refer [here](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/05/30/Indisposable-WCF-clients.aspx) and [here](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx)

Thanks for all!