# Is there a way to set the value of maxOccurs from "unbounded" to a specific number on an array/list item in a WSDL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wsdl

Is there any way to set the array size via an attribute in c# for objects that are generated into a WSDL?  I have a security requirement that requires arrays be limited in size to prevent DDoS attacks.

I know I can handle in code the max size very easily but for security purposes I must also output this max array size value into the WSDL.

I am trying to find a way to set the maxOccurs attribute of an object to a specific number rather than "unbounded".

Ex of the WSDL object currently:

```xml
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="GetCompanyListResult" nillable="true" type="tns:GetCompanyListResult"/>
```

I have tried looking at support with various attributes on the c# object but nothing seems to affect the WSDL generation.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class GetCompanyListResponse
{
     //Array object I want to set a array size limit of X (Ex: 100)
     public GetCompanyListResult[] Result;
     public int TotalRows;
}
```

I am trying to get it to output like this:

```xml
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100" name="GetCompanyListResult" nillable="true" type="tns:GetCompanyListResult"/>
```

Comment: You do know that nobody is bound to stick to the wsdl, right? Even if you put maxOccurs=100 in the XSD, clients can still submit 10000 items, still DoS-ing your service, depending how the XSD validator is doing its task.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839068/how-to-set-finite-value-to-maxoccurs-instead-of-unbounded-in-wcf